# update comma separated values in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Before we begin, this is a bad situation / design, but I am not the able to fix the design as the column is used by an application and database that I ( my company ) don't own.  I do not control the new or old values either.

I have a table similar to this:

```
Create Table #tblCRigrationTest 
( 
     ReasonString VarChar(1000), 
     ReasonStringNew VarChar(1000)
)
```

With data like this:

```
Insert Into #tblCRigrationTest ( ReasonString, ReasonStringNew )
Values ('5016|5005|5006|5032|5020|5010|5007|5011|5012|5028|5024|5008|5029', '')
```

What I need to do is "loop" through each ID and based on its value, update it, concatenate it into a new string, and then store it in the ReasonStringNew column.  The new ID's appear in the second column below:

```
Old     New
--------------    
5005        1
5006        2
5020        3
5032        4
5010        5
5007        6
5011        7
5012        8
5028        9
5024       10
5008       11
5016       12
5009       13
5029       14
```

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Google `SQL Split Function`

Comment: The new values don't make any sense. What is the logic of how you decide what the new value is? The biggest issue here as you know is the "design". You will have to first split this into rows so you can isolate each value. Once you have completed the update you will have to squash it all back together again. What a train wreck. Here is a great splitter. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/ and here is an article that explains how you can shove it back together. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/comma+separated+list/71700/

Comment: The REPLACE with CASE could work, however the values in the table ( Old / New ) are not always the same.

Comment: Sadly the values are controlled by the third party application provider, not me.

Comment: I know it is a 3rd party thing but what is the logic for what the new values need to become?

Comment: The company went from having multiple sources of this data to one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just take your column values in a temp table then try to update

```
    SET @STRSQL = 'SELECT ''' + REPLACE('Yourcolumn, ',',
                                                ''' ,(your saparator)''') + ''''

            DECLARE @tbl TABLE
                (
                  col1 VARCHAR(100) ,

                )

            INSERT  INTO @tbl
                    EXECUTE ( @STRSQL
                           )
```

Comment: SInce you were the only one that answered, your the winner...I was hoping for more dynamic solution, but at least you offered one.  ( I was already aware I needed to use Replace :)   )